# Unable to get oauth v2.0 access_token from v2.0 Azure tokenEndpoints

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, websphere, access-token

I have registered a multi-tenant app in Azure Active directory, I am using all oauth v2.0 endpoint in IBM Websphere OIDC TAI configuration. But still I am getting the accesss_token of v1.0, which has obviously a different issuer and hence it is failing in JWT validation while matching the issuer identifier. I am expecting this,

```
"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id/v2.0"
```

But I am getting this,

```
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/my-tenant-id/",
```

I am using Microsoft Graph APIs.

Comment: Have you configured `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have updated the manifest file, but it is still giving V1.0 access_token.

Comment: What scopes are you using?

Comment: The access token for Microsoft Graph is V1.0 for unknown reason. But for web API the access token will be v2.0. Microsoft Graph API access tokens are signed differently, you can't pass the JWT validation due to "Invalid Signature". So I don't think you need to validate the JWT . Just check the permission should be OK.

Comment: @juunas I am using openid as scope.

Comment: @AllenWu But IBM websphere does verify the issuer and the issuer I am getting in v1.0 token(https://sts.windows.net/my-tenant-id/) is not same what I am expecting (https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id/v2.0). How should I pass this?

Comment: Thanks Guys, the post in answer actually helped !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get an access token that can be validated in the standard way you need to 'expose an API scope' so that you get a verifiable token, as AllenWu says.

Azure AD behaviour is a little unintuitive and my [Visual Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) should enable you to work out what you need to do.

See steps 3, 6 and 7.

Comment: Yeah, can't request an MS Graph token and expect settings for your app to apply. You don't control that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your post !! It worked in my case, thanks for you help.